# C++/Arduino - pass one objects instance as a pointer(?) to another class

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

Forgive my ignorance with C++, I'm new here. Writing a custom class for some Arduino code.

I am using a TMC driver and library to control a motor. Simplified example:

```cpp
#include <TMCStepper.h>
TMC2209Stepper driver(&Serial1, 0.11f, 0b00);

void setup() {
   driver.begin();
   driver.rms_current(2000);
   driver.microsteps(32);
}

void loop() {
   // Set motor speed to 100
   driver.VACTUAL(100);
}
```

However I need to store various states and whatnot and the amount of which would clog up my main code. I instead want to create a custom class which would encapsulate my variables and functions. I envision it would work something like this:

```cpp
#include <TMCStepper.h>
TMC2209Stepper driver(&Serial1, 0.11f, 0b00);

#include <MyCustomController.h>
// pass "driver" as a pointer?
MyCustomController customControl(*driver);

void setup() {
   driver.begin();
   driver.rms_current(2000);
   driver.microsteps(32);
}

void loop() {
   // Set motor speed to 100
   customControl.setSpeed(100);
}
```

With the custom class looking something like this

```cpp
class MyCustomController {
   public:
      bool someState = false;
      bool someOtherState = true;

      void setSpeed(int speed) {
         // how do I get "driver" here?
         driver.VACTUAL(speed);
      } 
}
```

How do I pass `driver` from `main.cpp` to my `MyCustomController` class and use it as an "alias", pointer(?).

Comment: `*driver` - this is not *pass "driver" as a pointer*. The statement above is an example of passing a pointer. What error do you see? Doesn't it have a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to create a MyCustomController object that takes a driver as a constructor parameter, meaning that in order to create the object, you have to pass the driver as an argument. You can do this like so:

```
class MyCustomController {
public:
  bool someState = false;
  bool someOtherState = true;
  TMC2209Stepper* driver;

  MyCustomController(TMC2209Stepper* d) : driver(d) {} // <- this line here

  void setSpeed(int speed) {
     driver->VACTUAL(speed); // <- be careful, use "->" operator
  } 
}
```

This constructor (it's a constructor because it's a function with the same name of the class) takes a pointer to the driver, and save it as an object property.
Since you have a pointer to the driver, you now access its property through the operator -> instead of the "." operator (or you could also do (*driver).VACTUAL(speed)).

Now, in the main code, to pass a variable as a pointer, you don't have to use the "*" operator, but the "&" operator instead.
The "*" operator access the memory location of the pointer and returns the actual variable content.
The "&" operator gets the address of a variable.
You want to use the "&" operator because you want to store an address in your object, and then access its memory using the "*" (or the "->") operator.
So your code will be something like this:

```
#include <TMCStepper.h>
TMC2209Stepper driver(&Serial1, 0.11f, 0b00);

#include <MyCustomController.h>
// pass "driver" as a pointer?
MyCustomController customControl(&driver); // <- passing the drive address to
                                           // the MyCustomController constructor

void setup() {
   driver.begin();
   driver.rms_current(2000);
   driver.microsteps(32);
}

void loop() {
   // Set motor speed to 100
   customControl.setSpeed(100);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code sample and the explanation! Coming from scripted languages I'm struggling a bit and you not only showed how to do what I wanted, but explained how and I now have a better understanding overall. Thank you so much!!